# Diff b/w bitmap.recycle() and bitmap=null

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am in a situation where I have used a for loop to download a set of images and I am converting it into bitmap images. So in order to avoid OutOfMemory error, I am trying to recycle the bitmaps. But unfortunately I am running into another exception saying something like `"View trying to use a recycled bitmap"`.

But still I am allowed to null the used bitmap by using `bitmap=null`. So my question is, will making my bitmap `null` help me in freeing up the used memory? or should I provide `bitmap.recycle()` in some other part of my code?

Comment: following link gives more information on Bitmap memory management: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959485/bitmap-bitmap-recycle-weakreferences-and-garbage-collection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `recycle()` indicates to the system that you are finished using that resource and that the system may now free the unmanaged memory that it was using. Once you have disposed of a resource in this way, its behaviour is usually undefined (one would reasonably expect it to simply no longer work).

Setting the reference to null afterwards has two benefits:

- You won't have stale references to objects that won't work when you try to use them
- The garbage collector will know to clean up the managed side of the bitmap object, freeing even more memory

Answer (score 8):

There is no guaranteed way to force a garbage collection, only a way to suggest one using `System.gc()`.  Since the bitmaps pixel data lives in native memory outside of the dalvik heap, providing a native function (in this case `recycle()`) will give us the opportunity to clean up this pixel data for sure (eventually).  Please note that when using `recycle()` there is not much more you can do with that bitmap.

The issue you are having is that you are calling `recycle()` on a bitmap, which you are still trying to use.

To answer your question, yes, setting bitmap to null after you have recycled it is a good idea, but it may also be redundant.  Always try to recycle your bitmaps when you are done with them.

Comment: `Always try to recycle your bitmaps when you are done with them` this is what my question is. where should I provide recycle. If I try to provide within the for loop the app crashes. But I want to recycle as much as I can. So where can I have my recycle method exactly.

Answer (score -4):

just call bitmap.recycle() on onStop method .............u will solve the problem ..