# If set myBitmap = null without recycle(), what difference between with recycle()

Tags: android, bitmap

I see the two lines are always together:

```
myBitmap.recycle();
myBitmap = null;
```

If I only use:

```
myBitmap = null;
```

What difference?

Thanks.

Comment: Check here for answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260787/diff-b-w-bitmap-recycle-and-bitmap-null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```
public void recycle()
```

> **Free the native object associated with this bitmap**, and clear the
>   reference to the pixel data. This will not free the pixel data
>   synchronously; **it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there
>   are no other references.** The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it
>   will throw an exception if getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and
>   will draw nothing. This operation cannot be reversed, so it should
>   only be called if you are sure there are no further uses for the
>   bitmap. This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called,
>   since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no
>   more references to this bitmap.

So basically,

```
myBitmap = null;
```

Removes that specific reference to the bitmap it points to. If it's the only reference, that bitmap will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

However,

```
myBitmap.recycle();
myBitmap = null;
```

Removes a hidden reference to the pixel data for that bitmap. It then removes your specific reference to the bitmap. So both will be garbage collected. Unless you've got a huge bitmap, or for some reason have limited memory, you probably don't need to worry about calling myBitmap.recycle().